# Animation Transform by assembling all at center

Tags: transforms

Could you help me to arrange and modify or group objects at center without scaling but in a horizontal plane. All the objects are placed in a collection

[image: Before Assembly]

[image: After assembly]

Comment: What exactly do you want? As it seems now, the best way would be to set a location keyframe for each object when they are in their start location, then move forward on the timeline, move the objects in the end location and set location keyframes again.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Yes. True we can do that for 4 objects in all direction. But multiples of 100 of objects it is not possible to add keyframe for every action. For instance assembling multiple bolts/hardware manipulating away to its origin- better I ask here for any method in animation nodes or geometry nodes or traditionally method.